# When to set stack reserve size to 512MByte. Why can't create thread in visual studio?

Tags: c, multithreading, visual-studio, stack

After I set stack reserve size to 512MByte in visual studio 2015. I created thread by using "_beginthreadex" Function. But it didn't create thread. When thread is successfully created. As you know, We can get thread handle and thread ID. However, I saw that both thread handle and thread ID were 0. So I changed stack reserve size to 10MByte. then I could create thread successfully.
I really wonder this situation.

Comment: 512MB is a *large* stack...

Comment: Why would one even need so much stack?

Comment: @jameshyun do you have some recursive functions ?

Comment: My team member set it. I got project from him. so I don't need much stack like 512MB and I solved problem that I could not create thread. but I just wonder this situation.

Comment: Is it a 32-bit program?

Comment: Yes, It is a 32bit program.